# Stored procedure works on phpmyadmin but not in .net mvc code

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am working on an existing project. I have added a field to a database, and I have added it to the model class. Inserts are working as expected. I altered the existing stored procedure to select, and tested it on php my admin. The stored procedure works and returns results. However in my .net code, nothing is being returned. The result set is null and this I get

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in results:

I am lost, because I am new to .net mvc and C# in general

**Here is the code**

**The entity class**

```
public partial class MyClass : Entities<Entity>
{
    ...
    public string newField { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**The Data class**

```
 public class PostData
{
    ...
    public string newField { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**The APIObject**

```
public class APIClass : APIObject{[SecureLayer.AuthorizeRole(LoginRequired = true)]public async Task<object> Get(long x){
        var y = await DbInstance.DB.SelectMany<Data>(StoredQuery.get_all(x, 
                 SecureLayer.User.ID));
        return Normalize.NormalizeList(y, "y");
    }
```

}

**The Stored Query**

```
 public partial class StoredQuery{
 public static Query get_all(long id, int user_id)
    {
        return new Query("get_all", dict(new { id, user_id}));
    } }
```

Comment: How you are mapping the data tables with DB, Do you use any POCO,  auto mapper classes or Nhibernate mapper class then map it accordingly for the new columns as well. as @marc_s said please add some code for our reference or more information to understand the issue.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: `Could not find specified column in results` means your ORM requesting a column name which not exist in your SP's `SELECT` statement. Can you provide the query string inside stored procedure?

Comment: So the project runs on multiple databases. Turns out I was updating the wrong stored proc. Thanx

Comment: @Flora,Glad you found it.